# Wimpy Player unable to play from local server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wimpy

It seems wimpy player tries to append `http://root/link_i_provided` to find the location of the file.

I already have the location of my file which is on another server.  I can play this directly from the browser just fine so I know the link works.

```
wimpyButton.play('\\10.10.2.2\storage\calls\call1.wav')
```

It tries to turn my link into an http link like the following

```
http://mywebsite.com/10.10.2.2/storage/calls/call1.wav
```

Which of course it can't find.  What do I need to change within the Wimpy Player js to stop this behavior?  Or perhaps another solution?

EDIT

It looks like this may not be possilbe due to browser security.  I'd have to turn the server that holds the recordings into a web server and provide the links that way it seems.

Answer (score 1):

put your files needed on google drive inside a folder, then get the sharable link of that folder. with that you can reference files needed with www.googledrive.com/host/IdNumberOfFolderHere/fileNameOrNestedFolder/fileName.blah

Comment: While is is a nifty solution and would likely work for most needs, I can't transfer the 40 gigs of phone calls to google drive. =(  I'll have to find a solution that can play it directly from the server link.

Comment: it is appending the protocol beacuse to accessing things on the internet some protocol needs to be in place, such as http, https, ftp, etc...have you tried not using the IP address?

Comment: ip has to be present since it's a local server.  The website is not on the same server as the recorded calls.  I tries to pass in file:/// but wimpy player said playing from local storage isn't permitted or something to that extent.